# Using $this when not in object context in PHP

Tags: php, fatal-error

I don't know why i'm getting this error:  `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\index.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main}`

This is my `index.php` and where the error points out:

```
<?php 

require_once 'models/Request.php';

$req = new Request;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $data = [
        'reqBy' => $_POST['reqBy'],
        'off' => $_POST['off'],
        'prob' => $_POST['prob']
    ];

    echo "<pre>";
      print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";

    if($this->req->addRequest($data)){ //This is the line where it points the error
        echo 'Sucess';
    }else{
        echo 'Something';
    }
}
?>
```

I'm kinda lost solving this for half a day, so i'm reaching out here

Comment: You can use $this only inside classes.
`The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not inside instance of class to use $this. Try this, it will work

```
require_once 'models/Request.php';

$req = new Request;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $data = [
        'reqBy' => $_POST['reqBy'],
        'off' => $_POST['off'],
        'prob' => $_POST['prob']
    ];

    echo "<pre>";
      print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";

    if($req->addRequest($data)){ //This is the line where it points the error
        echo 'Sucess';
    }else{
        echo 'Something';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You canjust use your instance;

```
<?php 

require_once 'models/Request.php';

$req = new Request;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $data = [
        'reqBy' => $_POST['reqBy'],
        'off' => $_POST['off'],
        'prob' => $_POST['prob']
    ];

    echo "<pre>";
      print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";

    if($req->addRequest($data)){ //This is the line where it points the error
        echo 'Sucess';
    }else{
        echo 'Something';
    }
}
?>
```

It will access parent class properties also.

Comment: @Marat Badykov downvoted for my answer because I replied before him. Thats not cool bro.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$req->addReques` insted of `$this->req->addReques`